# Xcode templates: where does Xcode display the "Description" and "Summary" key values from TemplateInfo.plist?

Tags: xcode

Xcode templates have a TemplateInfo.plist where there are key values for `Description` and `Summary`. However, nowhere do these values appear when you create a file from a template. Where do they appear?

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the picker that comes up when you add a new file, the description and summary appear there.

Comment: Oddly, I don't see them there.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not seeing the descriptions for the template itself. If the descriptions are added to the variants themselves and you hover over them then they appear.
It may not be exactly what you're looking for but I've made a workaround in order to provide description of what the template does by adding a static variant to the options like so

```
<dict>
    <key>Identifier</key>
    <string>documentation</string>
    <key>Required</key>
    <true/>
    <key>Name</key>
    <string>Documentation:</string>
    <key>Default</key>
    <string>Creates Rx Delegate proxy and UI element + rx files</string>
    <key>Type</key>
    <string>static</string>
</dict>
```

Comment: It seems that the description field is broken in Xcode